# iphone memory management, real life scenarios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory

Ok I understand the basics of iphone memory management, the calls to retain and release must match up.

You can also autorelease which will get released when the memory pool gets flushed.

I still need real life scenerios to understand, why you would want to call retain and then release?

Is autorelease used allot and in what situations generally?

I just want to understand, under the iphone paradigm, how memory management should work, **are there patterns?**

Answer (score 2):

Write a real life program. Any program. Could be just a copy of something that already exists, but it will definitely learn you about memory management after some intensive use.

Better yet, write it and spread it to the general public (or the opensource community). The memory bugs you do not find will definitely be found by others.

The only true way of understanding something is to practice it (and make mistakes). And the only way to practice memory management is to actually use it (and make mistakes).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading the Cocoa Memory Management Guide cover to cover. You'll fully understand it by then.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the autorelease pool.  Everything put on the autorelease pool will be released at the end of the current event loop.

That means that the object your're using just for the treatment of an event, it is a good candidate for the AR pool but you also need to manage your state between events and for that you need to manually retain et release.  This is obviously an outrageously wrong simplification but it might help your understanding :-)

There a lot of other consideration to take into account and I really strongly advice you to read what Jasarien suggested.

Comment: Autorelease pools are not always tied to the event loop.  It is common to manually nest autorelease pools and Grand Central Dispatch has a pool that is drained "every now and then".